# Insert Hyperlink in Outlook body

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word, hyperlink, outlook-2010

So I am trying to create a code to expedite inserting a hyperlink in Outlook.

I am trying to have it so that if I have already copied a path, I can just go in and type Ctrl W and it will insert the hyperlink for the word here. My attempt at the code is:

```
Sub InsertHyperlink()
'
'
'
On Error Resume Next
ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, Address:= _
    "U:\plot.log", _
    SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:="here"
End Sub
```

I am having issues on how to update my code so that will work in Outlook (I programmed it in Word) and so that the "U:\plot.log" would actually be the copied path (not the copied path when I recorded the macro).

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to hit accept. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your references to Word object Library

***`Tools > References > add Word object Library`***

```
Option Explicit
Sub Add_Hyperlinks()
    Dim olNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim wDoc As Word.Document
    Dim rngSel As Word.Selection

    If Application.ActiveInspector.EditorType = olEditorWord Then
        Set wDoc = Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor ' use WordEditor
        Set olNameSpace = Application.Session
        Set rngSel = wDoc.Windows(1).Selection ' Current selection

        wDoc.Hyperlinks.Add rngSel.Range, _
        Address:="U:\plot.log", TextToDisplay:="Here is the link"
    End If

    Set wDoc = Nothing
    Set olNameSpace = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much for the help, I really appreciate it! So I made a slight variation to your code to try and get it to paste whatever is on the clipboard.

My new code is as follows. Do I need to add in any error trapping? Also, what does the option explicit exactly do?

```
Option Explicit
Sub Add_Hyperlinks()
   Dim olNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
   Dim wDoc As Word.Document
   Dim rngSel As Word.Selection
   Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject
   Set DataObj = New MSForms.DataObject
   DataObj.GetFromClipboard
If Application.ActiveInspector.EditorType = olEditorWord Then
    Set wDoc = Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor ' use WordEditor
    Set olNameSpace = Application.Session
    Set rngSel = wDoc.Windows(1).Selection ' Current selection
    wDoc.Hyperlinks.Add rngSel.Range, _
    Address:=DataObj.GetText(1), TextToDisplay:="here"
End If
Set wDoc = Nothing
Set olNameSpace = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think you need Error trapping - also see [option explicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)