# Add hyper link (web) to Outlook email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am having issues embedding a hyperlink to some text like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54101164/add-hyper-link-web-to-outlook-email).

I am running the macro from Excel which creates a Outlook object and repeats for all values down column c.

The below did not work so, **how do I go about embedding a link here?**

`.Body = "Click Here <https://www.google.com/>`

---

Code below

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

On Error GoTo cleanup
For Each cell In Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
       LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value) = "yes" Then

        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail

            .SentOnBehalfOfName = "urdearboy@needshelp.com"
            .to = cell.Value

            .Subject = "Subject" & Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value
            .Body = "Click Here <https://www.google.com/>"

             strLocation = "C:\Users\hahayouthought"
            .Attachments.Add (strLocation)

            .Display
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35882736/4539709 is this what you trying to do?

Comment: I don't think so, but am unsure. I am not well versed in Outlook VBA. Can you give an example of how to include that in a `.Body`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Try working with **`.HTMLBody`***

*Example*

> ```
> .HTMLBody = "<A href=https://www.google.com/> Click Here </A>"
> ```

***[MSDN HTMLBody Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa171418(v=office.11))***

*Returns or sets a String representing the HTML body of the specified item. The HTMLBody property should be an HTML syntax string. Read/write.*

***[MSDN .Body Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.MailItem.Body)***

*Returns or sets a String representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item. Read/write.*

Comment: @Om3r thanks I actually got the body recreated. I only have one last issue and i'm done - how do I embed a outlook email address using HTML? hmm

Comment: Nvm. I got it. Thanks so much! Project finished `<A href=mailto:urdearboy@needshelp.com> Hyper Link Text Goes Here</A>`