# Hyperlink stops at spaces in FilePath in VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to give a Hyperlink to a sharedrive path in eMail generated through VBA. In my excel, mail distribution list, mail subject & file path are dynamic hence VBA is picking these details from that particular cell. Since FilePath has 'space', hyperlink is not taking the entire path. Kindly see my code below and let me know where am I wrong-

```
Sub Draft_Mail()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim Filepath As String
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
Filepath = Worksheets("Macro").Range("F7")
    
With OutMail
.To = Worksheets("Macro").Range("F9").Text
.Cc = Worksheets("Macro").Range("F11").Text
.Subject = Worksheets("Macro").Range("F13").Text
.Attachments.Add Filepath
.htmlBody = "Hello-" & "<br/>" & "<br/>" & "Please find attached Reconciliation for " & Worksheets("Macro").Range("F5").Text & ". Click on this link to open the file-  " & "<br/>" & "<br/>" & "<A href=" & Filepath & ">" & Filepath & "</A>" & "<br/>" & "<br/>" & "Regards"
.Display

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35882736/4539709

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The href will need to be within quotes, like this...

```
"<A href='" & Filepath & "'>" & Filepath & "</A>"
```

Alternatively, you can replace any spaces in the file path with the url-encoded version `%20` like this...

```
"<A href=" & Replace(Filepath, " ", "%20") & ">" & FilePath & "</A>"
```